# How can I change Total Commander space left view from kB to GB?

Tags: total-commander

I use Total Commander a lot and I want it to show disk space left (above the tabs) in GB. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Configuration → Tabstops* and under "Header/footer:" select "dynamic (x.x k/M/G)".

The corresponding wincmd.ini setting is `SizeFooter=3`, as documented in *wincmd.chm → Configuration and Switches → Ini file Settings*:

> **SizeFooter=**
>
> Style of size display in the header and footer:
> 0=bytes, 1=kbytes, 2=dynamic, 3=dynamic with 1 digit fractional part,
> 4/5= like 2/3, but without GBytes (file sizes >1GB will still be shown in MBytes),
> 6/7= like 2/3, but with TBytes,
> 8/9= like 3/7, but with 2 digits fractional part.